# Why was my Stack Overflow account deleted? What happened to my old account?

Tags: support, accounts, deleted-users, merge-accounts

This account existed for years. I was in undergraduate courses in the IT area for more than 8 years before 2015.

But today, when I logged in (with the email and password I knew), the site told me that I was creating a new account. This surprised me. What happened to my old account and the reputation I think I had? I cannot vote the answer for the question I just did.

Comment: The account you are asking from has never existed before 5 days ago. Which account are you talking about?

Answer (score 9):

## Use the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https://stackoverflow.co) form, which is indirectly linked at the bottom of every page.

The account you're currently using is [this SE Network account](https://stackexchange.com/users/15455223/dedeco). The [oldest profile on an SE site associated with that account is on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/930874/dedec0), which was created 3 years, 3 months ago. Your profile on Stack Overflow was created a few days ago, on 2022-05-28. The moderator tools do not show a prior Stack Overflow profile associated with that network account (there are some cases where a prior profile won't be shown to moderators, so my not being able to see one doesn't mean there definitely isn't one).

There are indications that you *probably* have at least one other existing account/profile, but beyond that it doesn't appear appropriate for me to share more information here. However, what I've found isn't what I'd expect from your question, but that may just be my expectations. You may want to try logging in with any other email/password combinations which you remember.

There may or may not be anything which can be done for you. At a minimum, more information from you will be needed, but much of that information is considered private, so isn't appropriate to share here on Meta Stack Overflow. One thing that could be helpful is if you can identify, and link to, at least one post you created with your old profile (account). Knowing a post which you identify as created by your prior account/profile would at least identify the account/profile you are referring to.

Overall, there isn't going to be much which either users on Meta or moderators can do for you. Resolving this type of issue is something that will need to go through Stack Exchange staff. You should use the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https://stackoverflow.co) form, which is indirectly linked at the bottom of every page, to contact them.

Comment: As you were writing this, I found what I believe is their original account (which was not deleted) and filed a merge request with the community team. They should have been able to log into that account, not sure why a new one was created. The merge should sort that out and associate the right stuff.

Comment: I'm aware of the account which you found. I considered it *likely* to be theirs, but I did not consider there to be sufficient confidence that that account was theirs for there to be a merge without the involvement of the user, which really only happens through "Contact Us".

Comment: Yeah, I feel confident with the evidence we have, but I'll definitely appreciate the community team's eyes on this as final reviewers. I'm glad we don't have the ability to do merges ourselves like we once did.